# Deleted bash, how do I recover?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, bash, shell

I deleted `/bin/bash`. I had terminal open, but it auto-closed later. I am a normal user in `sudo` group.

What do I do? I'm panicked.

Can I change file permission of `/etc/passwd` with Python / Perl and change the shell script from `bash` to `zsh` in my username, then log out and log back in? I have to run Python / Perl from PHP because I don't have access to a terminal.

Or what do I do? This is Ubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Do you have any shell open? Or sshd enabled? BTW, i think this question is OT here, as it's not a production / enterprise system from what i understand

Comment: Install bash again

Comment: This is a desktop so I hadn't enabled SSH. The only open shell auto-closed.

Comment: can u try accessing from tty `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to get the virtual consoles

Comment: Shut it down, boot a live OS, mount the filesystem you messed with, replace the bash executable, start it up.

Comment: I tried to install Guake terminal from Ubuntu Software Center app but it  show error: `installArchives() failed: Error in function: `. How would I reinstal bash if I cannot open a terminal? In Software center, it asks to uninstall LightDM too to uninstall bash properly and install again.

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M just provided an answer. chroot into your installation and install everything you need

Comment: You can always install OS into VM, make a snapshot, then delete the bash and try all above recover stunt

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to reinstall bash, just as you would any package that is removed from your system. The tricky part is getting a shell, since your shell binary is now missing (ie: `/bin/bash`).

You should be able to either:

1. boot into a live cd environment like @SmallLoanOf1M mentioned. You'll need to chroot into your existing RFS, then do a reinstall of your bash package (so you'll need to set up networking to talk out to your configured repo's).

or

2. booting straight into single user mode by editing your boot-loader kernel arguments from grub directly by appending `/bin/sh` to your kernel arguments, then doing a reinstall of bash from there. YMMV here because you'll be working from `/bin/sh` which isn't going to give you the same built-ins, nor will you get your tab-autocompletion.

Of course option 2 is going to be preferable if possible.

Good luck!